# How to decrypt ByteArrayOutputStream in Java.?

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to decrypt a file downloaded as ByteArrayOutputStream from Azure Storage.

I have a stream of type ByteArrayOutputStream.
How can I decrypt it and return decrypted ByteArrayOutputStream.?

I have tried using CipherOutputStream, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Below is the code (snippet) I am using to encrypt the file before uploading

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(INITIALIZATIO_VECTOR.getBytes("UTF-8")));
blob.upload(new CipherInputStream(file.getInputStream(), cipher), file.getSize());
```

Below is my code:

```java
public ByteArrayOutputStream download(String fileName, Long id) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encrypkey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(INITIALIZATIO_VECTOR.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        CipherOutputStream output = null;
          
        container = getBlobClient().getContainerReference("container" + id.toString());
        
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        if (blob.exists()) {
            blob.download(os);
            //output = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);        
        } else {
            logger.info("File does not exists on azure container");
        }
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        logger.error("StorageException : {}" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception : {}" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
    
    return os;
}
```

Comment: How is it encrypted ?

Comment: What makes you think the file is encrypted?

Comment: I have encrypted it with another method and stored it in Azure storage. Here is snippet of code. cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(INITIALIZATIO_VECTOR.getBytes("UTF-8")));
          blob.upload(new CipherInputStream(file.getInputStream(), cipher), file.getSize());

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the `CipherOutputStream`, then download the blob into that output:

```
output = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
blob.download(output);
```

Comment: You may need an `output.flush()` after the download.

Comment: how to convert the output to ByteArrayOutputStream..?

Comment: @SanjaySingh you don't need to. Just return os.

Comment: @SanjaySingh BTW, you may want to consider returning a `byte[]` instead of a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: @SanjaySingh or else, pass an `OutputStream` as a parameter instead, and not returning anything (or a boolean indicating if a blob was found).